# Angular 5 change detection not firing for providers provided with useValue

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular 5 app that consists of several components and services that are coupled together using a 'broker' which is just an object with several RXJS Subject fields that can be used to receive status from the system or invoke commands. These services are being provided, but since there are no components injecting them directly they never get created.

To get around this, I provide them using the `useValue` field, like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DataBroker } from './brokers/data.broker';
import { SystemBroker } from './brokers/system.broker';
import { NotificationBroker } from './brokers/notification.broker';
import { LoggerService } from './services/logger.service';
import { SocketService } from './services/socket.service';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { SystemService } from './services/system.service';

const systemBroker: SystemBroker = new SystemBroker();
const dataBroker: DataBroker = new DataBroker();
const notificationBroker: NotificationBroker = new NotificationBroker();
const loggerService: LoggerService = new LoggerService(systemBroker);
const socketService: SocketService = new SocketService(loggerService, systemBroker, notificationBroker);
const dataService: DataService = new DataService(loggerService, socketService, dataBroker);
const systemService: SystemService = new SystemService(loggerService, socketService, systemBroker);

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: SystemBroker, useValue: systemBroker },
    { provide: DataBroker, useValue: dataBroker },
    { provide: NotificationBroker, useValue: notificationBroker },
    { provide: LoggerService, useValue: loggerService },
    { provide: SocketService, useValue: socketService },
    { provide: DataService, useValue: dataService },
    { provide: SystemService useValue: systemService },
  ]
})
export class AppServicesModule {
  constructor() { }
}
```

This does the job of creating the instances, but then I have a more painful problem: any data received in these services and passed to the components via the broker does not initiate change detection.

EDIT: As requested, an example of how data is passed through via the broker (this is just an example snippet, and keep in mind this exact same code works correctly with my workaround):

```
...
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(dataBroker: DataBroker, socketService: SocketService) {
    socketService.on('NETWORK_CONFIG', (value: NetworkConfiguration) =>
      dataBroker.networkConfiguration.status.next(value));
  }
}
```

If I provide these objects the typical way, i.e.:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DataBroker } from './brokers/data.broker';
import { SystemBroker } from './brokers/system.broker';
import { NotificationBroker } from './brokers/notification.broker';
import { LoggerService } from './services/logger.service';
import { SocketService } from './services/socket.service';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { SystemService } from './services/system.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    SystemBroker,
    DataBroker,
    NotificationBroker,
    LoggerService,
    SocketService,
    DataService,
    SystemService
  ]
})
export class AppServicesModule {
  constructor(systemBroker: SystemBroker
              dataBroker: DataBroker,
              notificationBroker: NotificationBroker,
              loggerService: LoggerService,
              socketService: SocketService,
              dataService: DataService,
              systemService: SystemService) { }
}
```

Then everything works as expected. I can use this as a workaround, but I'd like to understand the use case for `useValue` if it doesn't work in this context. It's a minor nitpick, but if there's a correct way to do this then I'd love to figure it out.

I'm sure the question will come up: "why not just use the services directly?" We use this broker pattern a lot to allow us to swap out service implementations without having to change our components.

Comment: `any data received in these services and passed to the components via the broker does not initiate change detection` Please provide a minimal working example reproducing the problem. Anyway your configuration looks strange

Comment: @yurzui care to elaborate on how my "configuration looks strange?" The comment itself isn't very helpful. I've added an edit to show you how I use Subjects in this context.

Comment: `We use this broker pattern a lot to allow us to swap out service implementations without having to change our components.` Have you tried using useClass to swap implementation instead of create it manually. You can just use `providers: [DataBroker]` in current code. And then change it to `providers: [provide: DataBroker, useClass: CustomBroker}]`

Comment: `and keep in mind this exact same code works correctly with my workaround` Where are you expecting to get updates? I would like to see a real example of this issue on stackblitz.com

Comment: @yurzui the broker implementation itself doesn't change, it remains constant, we only need to swap out service implementations. I have tried ``useClass`` on the service to no avail. I will work on getting a full minimal working example on stackblitz. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try factory provider instead

```
let dataServiceFactory = (dataBroker: DataBroker, socketService: SocketService) => { return new DataBroker(dataBroker, socketService); };

export let  dataServiceProvider= { provide: DataService, useFactory: dataServiceFactory, deps: [DataBroker, SocketService] };


@NdModule({
providers: [ dataServiceProvider ]
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I did try it, but it has the same problem in that no service is actually asking for the ``DataService`` to be injected, so it doesn't ever use the factory to create it.